Change colour of Back button and ToolbarItem for different scroll states
How can I change the colour of the Back button and the ToolbarItem in this state:

And separately change the colour of them when the toolbar background shows (i.e. when the user scrolls down):

Ideally, I want them to be white in the first screenshot, and the default blue colour in the second screenshot.
Here's the basic code:
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        //
    }
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
            Button(action: {
                //
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
            })
        }
    }
}


These posts might help: How can I change the color/style of ToolBarItem's when the toolbar changes from translucent to opaque in SwiftUI? How to trigger an action when a view passes under the navigation bar?

Use toolbar inside NavigationView...
If you only have two themes in your app, use @Environment(.colorScheme), which comes out of the box with SwiftUI...

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    private var isDarkMode: Bool {
        return colorScheme == .dark
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, Stackoverflow!")
                    .font(.title)
                    .foregroundColor(isDarkMode ? .red : .blue)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Text(isDarkMode ? "Dark mode" : "Light mode")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(isDarkMode ? .red : .blue)
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button {
                        // Action to perform
                        print("Button was tapped")
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(isDarkMode ? .red : .blue)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    NavigationStack {
        ContentView()
    }
}


If we're talking about scrolling up or down with a ScrollView, you will need to use a state property with element IDs and modifiers like onAppear/onDisappear or onChange, or do this custom using GeometryReader...

And yes, use NavigationStack instead of NavigationView if the minimum app version is iOS 16; if lower, use NavigationView...
